# Import module from parent directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

Take a look at my file structure:

```
main/
    main.py
    __init__.py

    mysql/
        read.py
        __init__.py

    conf/
        mysql.py
        loc.py
        __init__.py
```

`conf/mysql.py` contains the information of a mysql server (port,hostname,etc...)

`read.py` is used to acquire and read value from a MySQL DB by connect to the server specified in `conf/mysql.py`.

What I wanted to achieve is to let `read.py` import `conf/mysql.py`, so I tried:

```
from conf import mysql
import main.conf.mysql
```

Both of them are not working. It gives me `ImportError: No Module Name 'main'` and `ImportError: No Module Named 'conf'`, import `conf/mysql.py` only work in `main.py`

I know that appending to `sys.path` will work, but for some reasons, I don't wanna do that.

Any solutions to work around this issue? Thanks in advance and sorry for this complicated question.

Comment: Try this maybe: `from ../conf import mysql`

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Does not work, python said `/` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Make main as your current working project directory and script execution path in your IDE . It will work . Your code else use .sys.path (bad practice)to import the module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: @prashantrana All answer said append `sys.path`, but I find a better by appending sys.path, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `main` directory is the root directory of your project, you should not include `main` in your absolute import:

```
from conf import mysql
```

or with [relative import](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html), you can do:

```
from ..conf import mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax is correct, but now it give me another error: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`, any solution?

Comment: You should run your project from `main.py` and do `from mysql import read` in `main.py` instead.

Comment: `main.py` will call the function from `read.py`, so thats why I need to use relative import, Btw `from conf import mysql` does not work.

Comment: relative import does not work in python4.*