# Python import from another folder

Tags: python, import, directory, structure, sys

I made this structure as an example:

```
application
| main.py
├── folder
   ├── __init__.py
   └── file.py
```

when I want to import something in `main.py` from `file.py`, I can simply do

from folder.file import xy

but how can I import something in file.py from main.py?

It doesn't work, I tried sys, **init**.py files ...

Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, the structure in my question got messed up. folder contains file.py and is a subfolder.
and of course I mean __ init __.py

Comment: This question has a good overview of using Relative Import to import from modules in parent folders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863239/import-module-from-parent-directory

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should add path of main.py into file.py.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The result will be the list of path that file.py reads, so add the main path to this list by append method. Because this path is a parent directory, only put double dot before the current directory:

```
sys.path.append('../folder')
```

Then, you can import from main.py.

Comment: sorry, I answered in a new answer below, I never used Stackoverflow before for asking own questions ^^. Could you have a look at what I did there? :D

Answer (score 0):

```
# allows import from different folder
import sys
import os
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
directory = os.path.join(current, "..", "neural_network")
sys.path.append(directory)

import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
import keras.utils
from dense_layer import Dense_layer
from activation_functions import Tanh
from loss_functions import mse, mse_derivative
from network import train, save
```

Thank you for your reply. So I solved my problem with this solution, it works now, but my IDE (VSCode) says: Import "dense_layer" could not be resolved

Comment: Do you mean it's ok when you run your code from Terminal or CMD, and only in VS code this error happens?

Comment: Actually its no error. it works. it just gets highlighted